# Get children of multiple entries

Tags: elementquery

I'm sure this must be simple but I've tried multiple options with little success. What is the best way to build a query to get the children of more than one entry via an entry field?

For one parent would be:

```
{% set parent = craft.entries.id(parent_id).one() %}
{% for child in parent.children.all() %}
//Stuff
{% endfor %}
```

But I cant work out how to build the initial query to include more than one parent entry. The output I am looking for is a query that allows me to loop through all of the children from both(or more) entries selected. eg:

```
{% set query = craft.entries.id([4,35]).all().children.all() %}
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a method available to all element queries called `getDescendants()` (or like any method in Yii you can omit the `get` prefix and use `descendants()`):

```twig
{% for child in craft.entries.id([4,35]).descendants().all() %}
    <pre>{{ dump(child.title) }}</pre>
{% endfor %}
```

You can also pass in a `distance` integer if you want to limit to direct children/grandchildren.

https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/elements.html#methods

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you :)

Comment: Although saying that having just tried this it only returns the parent entry...no child entries are output using the above...

Comment: hm, I tested this and it worked ok for me. What version of Craft are you using?

Comment: Craft version: Craft Pro 4.4.13
Have tried a variety of things and can only return the parent entry. Interestingly looking through the docs and trying getAncestors() returns an error: Calling unknown method: craft\elements\db\EntryQuery::getAncestors()

Comment: Are _all_ of the entries you're querying part of a Craft Structure? Those methods are only available to such elements.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you get the children from each entry individually and then merge them together like so:

```
{% set childrenOne = craft.entries.id(entryID).one().children.all() %}
{% set childrenTwo = craft.entries.id(entryID).one().children.all() %}

{% set allChildren = childrenOne|merge(childrenTwo) %}
```

Comment: Beware that pretty much every time you write `.one()` or `.all()`, you are executing DB queries... and fairly heavy ones in the case of element queries. So I wouldn't recommend this way. You could mitigate slightly by eager loading the children: `craft.entries.id(entryID).with('children').one()`, but still not great.